# Change Output Directory in Dev C++

Tags: dev-c++

I want to separate .c/.cpp files and .exe files in different folders. 
How it's possible??

When I execute the code -

---

- C++ Compiler: C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin\g++.exe
- Command: g++.exe "D:\C\init\pointers\String.cpp" -o "D:\C\init\pointers\String.exe"  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib" -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib" -static-libgcc

Comment: "When [you] execute the code"... What?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes !!, when executing or compiling the code. The above output is when I execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

Necromancy here, I know, but I've just found myself in the same situation.
I'm using Dev-C++ 5.11, the current up to date fork, not the original Bloodshed one.

Dev-C++ allow to directly compile cpp files but the option you're looking for is related to project options. You must create a new project, add your code and then you can find it under "Project Options" -> "Output" -> "Executable output directory".